# How do I convert "for" in "mclapply"?

Tags: r, for-loop, mclapply

I have this:

```
# A simple "script" that receives an index
  ScriptR = function(i) {
    A = i^3;
  };

# With "for", pass the index "i" for "ScriptR"
  for (i in 1:10) {
     ScriptR(i);
  }; 

# How do I pass the index "i" for "ScriptR" function ??
  mclapply(1:10, ScriptR, mc.set.seed = FALSE);
```

How do I pass the index "i" for "ScriptR" function ??

Tks

Comment: What is wrong with `mclapply(1:10, ScriptR, mc.set.seed = FALSE)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work just fine. Since your function `ScriptR` has only one argument (that is, `i`), when you call `mclapply(1:10, ScriptR, mc.set.seed = FALSE)` the numbers `1:10` are being passed as arguments to `ScriptR`.  If you want to be more explicit, you could call `mclapply(1:10, function(i) ScriptR(i), mc.set.seed = FALSE)` but in this case there is really no need for that.